# Benefit of levelling up

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

What is the benefit of levelling up?
I understand that if you want to upgrade your cards you need a specific level depending on the card level.

Are there any other benefit of a player level? In-game the trooper/starfighter level is displayed instead of the global player level.

Comment: Its almost entirely as you say a requirement for cards and card upgrades.  There probably isn't much else.

Comment: OK, looks like that's it. Just add also the two trophies they felt compelled to add to really give a sense to the levels...

Comment: The whole point of progression is broken as EA had it designed around pay to win lootboxes and only after tons of backlash quickly added the "limitation" of upgrading cards based on your level and temporarily removed the ability to buy lootboxes with real money. There is little satisfaction of progression in their game at this time. Their P2W lootbox purchases will be back soon then just spend $100 on lootboxes and outgear everyone else. That is how they want you to progress sadly :/

Comment: I could be imagining this, but I feel like I earn more credits on each game (even when I do poorly), since passing Level 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also earn credits each time you level up. This appears to be [1000 credits per level](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsBattlefront/comments/7fvyvo/is_it_weird_you_dont_get_a_crate_from_ranking_up/), and increases to 2000 credits for the higher levels.